# How do I import a CSV file that has columns with different date formats into Weka?

Tags: weka

Suppose I have a CSV file, where the first column of data is a date with format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, while the second column is a date with format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`. How can I import the CSV file into the Weka Explorer such that both attributes have the "date" type?

I understand that in the Weka Explorer's "Preprocess" tab's "Open file ..." dialog, I can select "Invoke options dialog" to customize the data types of the imported attributes:

[image: Weka file selection window]

However, the resulting configuration window only allows me to specify one `dateFormat`:

[image: Weka CSVLoader configuration window]

How can I solve the problem? Do I have to manually convert the CSV file into an ARFF file by editing the CSV file in a text editor?

Answer (score 0):

The [ADAMS framework](https://adams.cms.waikato.ac.nz/) has the `weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToDate` filter that allows the conversion of a range of attributes using a specific date format string. You can wrap multiple of these filters in a `weka.filters.MultiFilter` to convert all of your various date columns in one go. The `MultiFilter` would get applied to the initially loaded CSV file, where all the date columns are just string columns.

ADAMS also offers the **Weka Investigator**, a more powerful tool than the Weka Explorer: multi-session support, multiple files loaded at the same time (you can load train and test files and just select the files from a combobox then), multiple tabs of the same kind (not just a single Classify tab), different types of cross-validation (batched/non-batched), predefined output generators that get applied to evaluations (model, statistics, classifier errors, ...), etc.

Also, for automating all these steps, you can use ADAMS' **Flow editor**, a workflow engine.

If you don't want to use ADAMS: load the CSV file in the Weka Explorer, save it as ARFF then manually edit the relevant attribute types (see [ARFF format](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/arff_stable/)) before reloading it in the Weka Explorer.